# Replacing the Faceplate on an after-factory Alpine stereo

Tags: audio

I bought an Alpine CDE-9841 stereo and now I'd like to upgrade to a unit with an auxiliary port. I was wondering if I could leave the receiver in place and just purchase a new faceplate. I can't find any information on the compatibility of different faceplates with the same receiver. It seems like there might be a standard port connecting the faceplates, based on my minimal experience with two different stereos.

Comment: Yes , you can do that provided they are of the same DIN type, will give an answer when i find time.

Comment: What is the model of the faceplate you are planning to use?

Comment: I have no planned faceplate - I'm trying to find out what's compatible so that I can find one to buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faceplates are usually not interchangeable between models, however, I have heard the odd case of people doing this with Pioneer decks.

While the new faceplate may fit in your Alpine head unit, all of the functions may not work correctly. The pins on the faceplate would have to match exactly with those on the head unit and thus the manufacturer would have to provide if it is compatible or not. I think it would be best to contact [Alpine](http://alpine-usa.com/company/contact) for the information you require.

There are other ways of adding an auxiliary port to your system (see [here](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/07/19/how-to-add-an-audio-jack-to-your-car-stereo/) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_transmitter_(personal_device))). Nevertheless, getting a head unit with an auxiliary port (and not just the faceplate) is probably the best option in terms of sound quality.